# Accessing radio button values from controller

Tags: scala, radio-button, playframework-2.0

I am trying to access the selected radio button values in controller it returns value as list

My View is :

```
@(img:Form[Image])
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.abc) {
    <li><input name="item[0]" value="pt" type=checkBox></li>
            <li><input name="item[1]" type=radiobutton value=acepted>
                <input name="item[1]" type=radiobutton value=@path(i)>
            </li>
    <p>
               <button type=submit id=imgButton>submit</button>
    </p>

    }
```

My Controller is :

```
def DeleteImages=Action{

   implicit request =>
     val values =ImageForm.bindFromRequest.get
     println(values)
     Ok("hi "+values)
 }
```

My case class is :

```
case class Image (desc:List[String])
```

On submit of form DeleteImages gives me outcome as :

```
Image(List(acepted, images/pics/6.jpg"))
```

I want to itterate in above list so that I can find path from list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pattern match on the `Image` case class to extract the `List`.

```
scala> case class Image (desc:List[String])
defined class Image                                                                                                            

scala> val image = new Image(List("cat", "dog", "cat"))
image: Image = Image(List(cat, dog, cat))                                                                                      

scala> image match {
     | case Image(xs: List[String]) => xs.foreach(println(_))
     | }
cat
dog
cat
```

Comment: I have tried your code in terminal it is executed correctly, but in play framework it is showing following errors " non variable type-argument String in type pattern List[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure"

Comment: Try this version: `scala> image match {
     | case image: Image => image.desc.foreach(println(_))
     | }`. Note the first use of `image` is the `val image = ...` that was declared and the second use `case image: Image = ...` is a different variable.

Comment: Or `case Image(xs) => xs.foreach(println(_))`. `xs` is already guaranteed to be `List[String]` and there is no need to test it in the pattern.

Comment: @Brian : Instead of printing elements in foreach how can I store elemnts in variables?